# how to add an animation effect of drawing a circle in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

i am working on a game to spot the difference between 2 images.

I want to add an effect when you spot it. drawing out a circle would be much better than just showing the circle suddenly. but i've never done core animation or opengl before.

i don't think preparing 100 sprites and changing the sprite frame by frame is a good idea. 
here is my code: (just add a circle image to both left and right image. )

```
-(void) show {
    CCSprite* leftCircle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"circle.png"];
    CCSprite* rightCircle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"circle.png"];
    leftCircle.scaleX = size.width / [leftCircle boundingBox].size.width;
    leftCircle.scaleY = size.height / [leftCircle boundingBox].size.height;
    rightCircle.scaleX = size.width / [rightCircle boundingBox].size.width;
    rightCircle.scaleY = size.height / [rightCircle boundingBox].size.height;
    leftCircle.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);
    rightCircle.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);
    leftCircle.position = leftPosition;
    rightCircle.position = rightPosition;
    [[GameScene sharedScene] addChild:leftCircle z: 3];
    [[GameScene sharedScene] addChild:rightCircle z: 3];
    shown = YES;
}
```

So how can i implement it? It would be great if you can provide some source code.

Comment: and also i need to implement the drawing effect of 'wrong cross'. line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple way i can recommend you to create a circle and put it's scale to zero. Then create a CCScale action and run it. It will give you a growing circle. Here is the code:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"];
[sprite setScale:0.01];
id scale = [CCScale actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:1];
[sprite runAction:scale];
```

The other action can be used is CCFadeIn.You can make your sprite invisible after creation and make it fade in:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"];
[sprite setOpacity:0];
id fade = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.3];
[sprite runAction:fade];
```

Also you can combine this actions:

```
[sprite runAction:fade];
[sprite runAction:scale];
```

Also you can make it big (set scale 3 for example) and transparent. And make it fade in and scale down to highlight your image

To Draw a circle via drawing effect you can make it from small parts (arcs) and then build your circle from them. I think it also will be cool if you make don't make the part visible when adding, but make it fade in. I mean something like this:

```
-(void) init
{
    NSMutableArray *parts = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; //store it in your class variable
    parts_ = parts;
    localTime_ = 0; //float localTime_ - store the local time in your layer
    //create all the parts here, make them invisible and add to the layer and parts
}

-(void) update: (CCTime) dt //add update method to your layer that will be called every simulation step
{
    localTime_ += dt;

    const float fadeTime = 0.1;
    int currentPart = localTime_ / fadeTime;

    int i = 0;
    for (CCSprite *part in parts)
    {
        //setup the opacity of each part according to localTime
        if (i < currentPart) [part setOpacity:255];
        else if (i == currentPart)
        {
            float localLocalTime = localTime - i*fadeTime;
            float alpha = localLocalTime / fadeTime;
            [part setOpacity:alpha];
        }
        ++i;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, not exactly what i want. but definitely a simple candidate approach if i can't figure out how to make the drawing effect. (just like actual drawing, start from a point and draw a circle)

Comment: you mean using a for loop like: [parts addObject: [CCSprite spriteWithFile: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"part%i.png", i]]]; which means i need to create many png images?

Comment: isn't that the same as creating an animation with many sprite images?

Comment: @Let: No. I mean create them all in the init method and make them all transparent. Put them to the correct positions (so the make circle) and add to the array to have access to them. Then in update method update their alpha-value (transparency) according to localTime_.

Comment: ok, i will try it tmr. but creating partN.png files will be troublesome. Maybe a better approach would be opengl stuff, like the blade effect in fruit ninja. i sucks at opengl...or maybe record the computer screen as i draw, i don't think i can embed an mp4 file into the game.

Comment: @Let: you need only one part.

Comment: but i still need to position them correctly? part by part? is there a way to fade in from start to end? i also need a 'wrong cross', line by line

Comment: @Let: Yes, you need to position them, but it's really easy. There is no way to fade one part from start to end. But If you will have many parts it will look cool when the fade one after another. What do you meen by wrong cross ?

Comment: when player tapped the wrong place, i need a red cross to indicate it. line by line, just like writing it out.

Comment: Hi andrew, I've decided to use your first way. but the My scaleX and scaleY is different(determined by the shape of different spot), Could you modify your code? i don't know how to scale x/y independently.

Comment: also i want it to scale up a bit, then scale down, ->up->down->...like bouncing effect. Thank you!

Comment: @Let: You can use CCActions for this. But i recommend to do it manually. Create an -(void) update; method and specify the scale manualy.

Comment: How? If i use update, i am not able to use callback function. Could you change your code a bit? i'd prefer ccactions since it's simple, and update is hart to configure the time and speed.

Comment: Create an empty CCNode and add all the sprites to it, when creating circle. Then create CCScaleBy, possilby CCActionInterval and put the all into CCSequence. Then run this action on a node. You can also run the action when creating circle

Comment: yeah, that's how i did it. but the scaleX and scaleY is different. I have a class Circle.m, then outside the class, i scale X and Y according to texture of parent class. so scaleX != scaleY. What i want is scale the x and y independently. (CCScaleTo actionWithScale: 2.0 * originalScale duration: 0.5f] can only apply to both scaleX and scaleY

Comment: ok, i understand to use scaleby instead of scaleto. but still i need a bouncing effect. and i declared up1-down1-up2-down2-up3-down3,etc. the result is quite ugly. any way to make the bouncing effect more natural?

Comment: @Let: add new question about the bouncing effect

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple to create the effect you want.
You can realize it by setting the strokeEnd of a CAShapeLayer.

Here are the details:

1. create a path you then assign to a CAShapeLayer

   ```
   UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) radius:80.0 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270.01) clockwise:NO];

   circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   circle.path = circlePath.CGPath;
   circle.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
   circle.fillColor   = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
   circle.lineWidth   = 6.0;
   circle.strokeEnd   = 0.0;

   [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];
   ```
2. set the strokeEnd to implicitly animate the drawing of the circle

   circle.strokeEnd = 1.0;

That's it! The circle will be automatically drawn for you ;). Here is the code from above with a GestureRecognizer to trigger the animation. Copy this to an empty project of type "Single View Application" and paste it to the ViewController.

```
    #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) radius:80.0 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270.01) clockwise:NO];

        circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        circle.path = circlePath.CGPath;
        circle.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        circle.fillColor   = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        circle.lineWidth   = 6.0;
        circle.strokeEnd   = 0.0;

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

        // add a tag gesture recognizer
        // add a single tap gesture recognizer
        UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    }


    #pragma mark - gesture recognizer methods

    //
    // GestureRecognizer to handle the tap on the view
    //
    - (void)handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

        circle.strokeEnd = 1.0;
    }
```